# Inner Joining 3 queries

Tags: php, sql

I would like to know how I could join these 3 queries together as I'm wanting only one JSON output, I thought INNER JOIN would do this. But don't know how to use this. Can someone guide me onto the right path please?

```
  $json = array();
$following_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$call="SELECT * FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_id < '$lastID' AND streamitem_target=".$following_string." OR streamitem_creator=".$following_string." ORDER BY streamitem_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$chant = mysqli_query($mysqli, $call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$json['streamdata'] = array();

while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chant)) {

    $json['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id'];
    $json['streamitem_content'] = $resultArr['streamitem_content'];
    $json['streamitem_timestamp'] = Agotime($resultArr['streamitem_timestamp']);

 $json['streamdata'] = $json;
}

/***** COMMENTS *****/
$check = "SELECT comment_id, comment_datetime, comment_streamitem, comment_poster, comment_content FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_poster=".$following_string." ";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$json['streamdata_comments'] = array();

while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check1)) {

    $json['comment_id'] = $resultArr['comment_id'];
    $json['comment_content'] = $resultArr['comment_content'];
    $json['comment_poster'] = $resultArr['comment_poster'];
    $json['comment_datetime'] = Agotime($resultArr['comment_datetime']);
    $json['comment_streamitem'] = $resultArr['comment_streamitem'];

$json['streamdata_comments'] = $json;
}

/***** USERS *****/

$check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$following_string."";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$json['users'] = array();

while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check1)) {

    $json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
    $json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
    $json['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
    $json['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
    $json['last'] = $resultArr['last'];

$json['users'] = $json;
}


echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

Comment: "But don't know how to use this" --- have you tried to read documentation?

Comment: It should be 'do this'. But yes I have and haven't got a clue.

Comment: what specifically have you read?

Comment: Whilst its not MYSQLI_ Its almost the same. I tried to use this as an example. http://www.w3cyberlearnings.com/PHP_MySQL_Query_Use_INNER_JOIN

Comment: If you don't know what to read - the wikipedia isn't the bad alternative for everything --- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) PS: learning by blindly repeating examples without reading some text usually makes no sense

Comment: You probably have a problem with the '`conditionA AND conditionB OR conditionC`' in your query.  It groups as if you had written '`(conditionA AND conditionB) OR conditionC`' but the symmetry of the conditions suggests you might have intended '`conditionA AND (conditionB OR conditionC)`'.  I'd strongly recommend using parentheses to make the correct interpretation unambiguous to both the DBMS and (more particularly) the maintainers of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some previous answers have suggested that you can't join unrelated tables, but these are clearly not unrelated tables.  The `streamdata` and `streamdata_comments` tables are quite closely related, and the `users` table maps user ID values in the other tables to names.

At the SQL level, these can be combined easily:

```
SELECT d.*, c.*, u.*
  FROM streamdata          AS d
  JOIN streamdata_comments AS c ON d.streamitem_ID = c.comment_streamitem
  JOIN users               AS u ON u.user_id = c.comment_poster
 WHERE c.comment_poster = '$following_string'
   AND d.streamitem_id < '$lastID'
   AND (d.streamitem_target  = '$following_string' OR
        d.streamitem_creator = '$following_string');
```

Whether the result makes sense for wrapping into a JSON string is a different matter, on which I can't pontificate.  This would give you one record from the comments information for each comment associated with each stream item.

Comment: Maybe you could help me with something @Jonathan, I've updated my question code with what I've got so far. I need to print out 10 results. and whilst My code is now working nearly and my response in firebug has these 10 results its only showing 1 when I click load more results. What do I need to do to rectify this.

Comment: @dave: Succinctly, I don't know.  Perhaps the trouble is that you're assigning to `$json` rather than adding to it.  You should look at the SQL you're generating, and at the results returned as they are returned.  That will tell you what the DBMS is giving you.  You then have to work out how to package that properly in JSON.  If the row shown is the last row of the set you expected, then I'd assume that my 'overwrite instead of append' diagnosis is probably correct.  But you're beyond my knowledge when it comes to how to rectify it.

Answer (score 2):

You're fetching unrelated data, so you can't use a join at the SQL level.

But JSON couldn't care less WHAT you feed it, or how. Just build the appropriate PHP-level data structure, e.g.

```
$data = array();
$data['streamdata'] = array();
... insert data from 'streamdata' query...
$data['streamdata_comments'] = array();
... insert comment data ...
$data['users'] = array();
... insert user data ...
```

which will give you a 3-way array containing the data from each of your queries. You then pass that entire `$data` structure to json_encode, and boom - you've got your 3 unrated queries in a single data structure, without every touching an SQL join.

Comment: This works perfect. Only now its only sending back 1 result. I need it to send 9 more. How would I do this?

Comment: I've got part of it. In firebug i've got 10 results in my response by using  $json['streamdata'] = $json; in the loop/. But only 1 result prints out in my site. Nearly there.

Comment: you need to build an array, you're just assigning a string over and over. make it `$json['streamdata'][] = $json`. note the extra `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching unrelated data. Joining data is only usefull when the data to join has a relation.

You can't join apples, cows and monkeys.

Comment: `... where life_type='carbon_based'`?

Comment: So how is it possible for me to join the arrays together to output as one in json_encode($json);